# SeleniumWebDriver FluentAutomation Chrome incognito

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, incognito-mode, fluentautomation

We are using `FluentAutomation.SeleniumWebDriver` to drive our integration tests.  We configure this as so

```
public IntegrationTest()
{
    SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Chrome);
}
```

My question is how do I tell it to run in incognito mode? The problem I have is that the tests will sometimes use cookies that I have been using locally and this can affect tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to always force it to run in icognito mode, but it might be helpfull that you can always open a new window in incognito mode and use that.

```
_driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body").SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "n");
```

You can switch between windows as following:

```
//switch to new window.
_driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.Last());
//switch back to your first window
_driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.First());
```

I know this doesn't give you excatly what you wanted but maybe it can sovle some of your problems.

Comment: I tried using the same code with chrome driver v2.25 and chrome v54. Could not get it to work.